# I need to use 2 different SoapServices but I can only access 1 at the time, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

I have a school assignment and I've run into a problem which I just can't understand what's wrong.

In my school assignment we created a Service which is identical to my teachers service. The point of the service were to be able to communicate with our chat clients which we connected to our service.

The problem I have is when I got the task to be able to switch between the two services (which is the type servicename.ServiceSoapClient("ServiceSoap12")). In my service, which I created I put in a namespace to my teachers service: [WebService(Namespace = "http://dsweb.tmd.hv.se/users/wsi400/ChatService/")]
(That was for a later purpose, see below)

The code for my service (which should be almost identical (same return and input values)) is here: http://pastie.org/2461928

**Now to the real problem..**

When creating the client for one service is a piece of cake, trying it to be able to change between them using only 1 reference in the client seems impossible (but others have managed to do it, but after examination of code and such, we have no idea what's wrong with mine). I have, as I've said added the local reference to my service (my asmx file) and that's because I apparently needed the namespace pointed to my teachers service from mine.

When connecting to my service I use the following code:

```
   wsChatService.ServiceSoapClient wsService = new wsChatService.ServiceSoapClient("ServiceSoap12");
```

When adding my service, it generates a lot of stuff in app.config and I changed a value to be able to switch to my teachers service:

```
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://dsweb.tmd.hv.se/users/wsi400/ChatService/Service.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap" contract="wsChatService.ServiceSoap"
            name="ServiceSoap" />
        <endpoint address="http://dsweb.tmd.hv.se/users/wsi400/ChatService/Service.asmx" binding="customBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap12" contract="wsChatService.ServiceSoap"
            name="ServiceSoap12" />
    </client>
```

Now I have tried to switch with a simple button and the test function always works when switching between the services but depending on what service I choose to use as an assembly reference, that's the one that I can post messages to.

This is the code for the client:

```
    private void service1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (connNr == 2)
        {
            wsService = new wsChatService.ServiceSoapClient("ServiceSoap12", "http://localhost:63280/Service.asmx");
            connNr = 1;
            MessageBox.Show("Connection changed to: Markus \nTesting connection: " + wsService.Test());
            textarray.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Trying to send message: " + wsService.SendMessage("babbel", "Connecting..", "Connected?"));
        }
    }

    private void service2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (connNr == 1)
        {
            wsService = new wsChatService.ServiceSoapClient("ServiceSoap12", "http://dsweb.tmd.hv.se/users/wsi400/ChatService/Service.asmx");
            connNr = 2;
            MessageBox.Show("Connection changed to: http://dsweb.tmd.hv.se/users/wsi400/ChatService/Service.asmx \nTesting connection: " + wsService.Test());
            textarray.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Trying to send message: " + wsService.SendMessage("babbel", "Connecting..", "Connected?"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You posted a _lot_ of code. Can you reduce that to the amount of code necessary to reproduce the actual problem? Also, be sure to include the namespace used by your and your teacher's services.

Comment: The problem is that the code posted does not generate any actual problem. Tho my experience in C# and .NET in general isn't that great I don't really know what the problem may be. But I can give it a try :)

Comment: This is the namespace I used: 

`namespace Service
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://dsweb.tmd.hv.se/users/wsi400/ChatService/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]`

My teachers code is unavailble to me, but I think the namespace he is using refers to his asmx-file.

Answer (score 0):

I used to run into this all the time
This issue is usually because of the namespace used in the WSDL definition.  for example I used to have issues with .NET clients of my PHP SOAP services on different servers.

I used namespaces such as dev.myserver.co.uk, test.myserver.co.uk and srv1.myserver.co.uk respectively on my development, test and live servers.  When I did this my .Net clients had to  be rebuilt each time, like the issue you are experiencing.

I changed my namespace to a fictional one (namespaces don't have to actually exist) xml.myserver.co.uk on each of my web services and then you can re-use the generated proxy classes in your C# client apps.

The problem is that if you don't control the definition for the WSDL then you can't easily change it.

One hacky way around it is to save the WSDL definition locally, make your changes and have your client point to that instead.  That way you can re-use the proxy class but invoke the methods against different servers.

Comment: I am not sure what you are suggest I should do? I'm sorry but I don't understand how to solve this by your answer, sorry! Could you maybe explain it more detailed?

Comment: post the wsdl definition for the service.  You've posted your code but not the wsdl defs

Comment: It's pretty huge, I'll link my definition onto pastie (since it's local).

http://pastie.org/2462110 <- Mine
http://dsweb.tmd.hv.se/users/wsi400/ChatService/Service.asmx?WSDL <- My teachers

Comment: change the targetNamespace value in your version to the same as your teachers service. targetNamespace="http://dsweb.tmd.hv.se/users/wsi400/ChatService/"  Try it again.

Comment: ... um, yeah i see that now...  Are you using the WSDL.exe tool to generate classes you can use to interact with these services?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3043/discussion-between-ghostjago-and-cubsink)